# CSS svg hover animation/transition

Tags: html, css, svg, transition, clip-path

im using a svg clip-path as mask for an image.
Now i want an inner border inside it on hover.
So i made a second clip-path for hover but the transition doesnt affect it.

I want the border comming from the sides (reducing zoom/negative scaling).
Here you can see what i want without working animation/transition:

```css
body {
 background: #ccc;
}

.clip-svg {
  position: relative;
 display: block;
 height: 400px;
 width: 300px;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: auto 100%;
 clip-path: url(#Emblem);
 transition: 0.4s all ease;
}
.clip-svg:hover {
 clip-path: url(#Emblem2);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-svg" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/864994/pexels-photo-864994.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260)"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="Emblem">
      <path d="M279,240c0,96-139.4,145-139.4,145S22,336,22,240c0-58,0-203,0-203s65-11,129-11c75,0,128,11,128,11S279,136,279,240z"/>
    </clipPath>
 <clipPath id="Emblem2">
     <path d="M39,51.6V240c0,72.4,80.9,116.6,101.2,126.5c11-4.5,35.7-15.4,59.8-32.3c18.5-13,33.2-26.8,43.6-41.3
  c12.2-17,18.4-34.8,18.4-53V51.3C240.8,48,200.9,43,151,43C106.3,43,59.9,48.7,39,51.6z"/>
 <path d="M151,26C87,26,22,37,22,37s0,145,0,203c0,96,117.6,145,117.6,145S279,336,279,240c0-104,0-203,0-203S226,26,151,26z
   M270,240c0,19.9-6.7,39.3-19.9,57.7c-10.9,15.1-26.2,29.7-45.5,43.1c-26.2,18.3-52.8,29.8-63.1,33.8l-1.6,0.6l-1.6-0.8
  c-10.4-5-37.2-18.9-61.3-41.3c-30.5-28.4-46-59.7-46-93.2V44.7l3.4-0.5C53.5,41.4,103.1,35,151,35c53.2,0,95.3,5.6,115.6,8.9
  l3.4,0.5V240z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<br/>
Image: <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/woman-wearing-white-top-holding-smartphone-and-tablet-864994/">https://www.pexels.com/...d-tablet-864994/</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would consider two layers each one using a `clip-path` and I would control the `opacity`:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.clip-svg {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
.clip-svg::before,
.clip-svg::after {
   content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-image: var(--i);
  transition: 0.8s all ease;
}

.clip-svg::before {
  clip-path: url(#Emblem2);
}

.clip-svg::after {
  clip-path: url(#Emblem);
}
.clip-svg:hover::after {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-svg" style="--i: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/864994/pexels-photo-864994.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260)"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="Emblem">
      <path d="M279,240c0,96-139.4,145-139.4,145S22,336,22,240c0-58,0-203,0-203s65-11,129-11c75,0,128,11,128,11S279,136,279,240z"/>
    </clipPath>
 <clipPath id="Emblem2">
     <path d="M39,51.6V240c0,72.4,80.9,116.6,101.2,126.5c11-4.5,35.7-15.4,59.8-32.3c18.5-13,33.2-26.8,43.6-41.3
  c12.2-17,18.4-34.8,18.4-53V51.3C240.8,48,200.9,43,151,43C106.3,43,59.9,48.7,39,51.6z"/>
 <path d="M151,26C87,26,22,37,22,37s0,145,0,203c0,96,117.6,145,117.6,145S279,336,279,240c0-104,0-203,0-203S226,26,151,26z
   M270,240c0,19.9-6.7,39.3-19.9,57.7c-10.9,15.1-26.2,29.7-45.5,43.1c-26.2,18.3-52.8,29.8-63.1,33.8l-1.6,0.6l-1.6-0.8
  c-10.4-5-37.2-18.9-61.3-41.3c-30.5-28.4-46-59.7-46-93.2V44.7l3.4-0.5C53.5,41.4,103.1,35,151,35c53.2,0,95.3,5.6,115.6,8.9
  l3.4,0.5V240z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to achieve what you want using clip paths on an HTML element.  You can only replace one clip path with another in CSS.  You can't interpolate between two of them.

However it is fairly easy to do, if you are okay with moving the image into an SVG.  Then you can do whatever you want with the inner border.

Note however, with this solution, the inner border is not a clip path, so it doesn't make the image transparent.  I don't know if that is important to you or not.  It should be possible to do that if you really need it to.

```css
body {
 background: #ccc;
}

.clip-svg .emblem2-ref {
  transform-origin: 150px 200px;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
 transition: 0.4s all ease;
}
.clip-svg:hover .emblem2-ref {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

#Emblem2 {
  fill: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!-- Clip path and inner border definitions. Can be included once and used by multiple SVGs -->
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="Emblem">
      <path d="M279,240c0,96-139.4,145-139.4,145S22,336,22,240c0-58,0-203,0-203s65-11,129-11c75,0,128,11,128,11S279,136,279,240z"/>
    </clipPath>
    
    <path id="Emblem2"
          d="M39,51.6V240c0,72.4,80.9,116.6,101.2,126.5c11-4.5,35.7-15.4,59.8-32.3c18.5-13,33.2-26.8,43.6-41.3
             c12.2-17,18.4-34.8,18.4-53V51.3C240.8,48,200.9,43,151,43C106.3,43,59.9,48.7,39,51.6z
             M270,240c0,19.9-6.7,39.3-19.9,57.7c-10.9,15.1-26.2,29.7-45.5,43.1c-26.2,18.3-52.8,29.8-63.1,33.8l-1.6,0.6l-1.6-0.8
             c-10.4-5-37.2-18.9-61.3-41.3c-30.5-28.4-46-59.7-46-93.2V44.7l3.4-0.5C53.5,41.4,103.1,35,151,35c53.2,0,95.3,5.6,115.6,8.9
             l3.4,0.5V240z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>

<!-- Will need one of these SVGs for every image you want to display -->
<svg width="300" height="400" class="clip-svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#Emblem)">
    <image width="300" height="400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
           xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/864994/pexels-photo-864994.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"/>
    <use class="emblem2-ref" xlink:href="#Emblem2"/>
  </g>
</svg>


<br/>
Image: <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/woman-wearing-white-top-holding-smartphone-and-tablet-864994/">https://www.pexels.com/...d-tablet-864994/</a>
```